# How to limit the number of times the header prints?

Tags: sas, mainframe, sas-ods

Every time that I print out a job from tso mainframe using SAS I get something like this:

```
Obs Name Amount
1   John  10
2    Ben  20

Obs Name Amount
3    Jen  15
4    Pat  20
```

Basically, I get the headers multiple time in the output. I'm using:

```
OPTIONS NODATE NONUMBER;
TITLE1; TITLE2;

PROC PRINT DATA=DATASET;
RUN;
```

What else should I add to get a better output?

Comment: How many actually come out before the titles are repeated?  I suspect this is `options ps=` issue.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, what you're getting multiple times are the column headers, not the titles. You've correctly suppressed the titles using the `TITLE` statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The titles are repeated once per page normally; a page is controlled by `options ps=`.

```
options ps=100;
```

would give you 100 line pages, for example.

Comment: Gotta give you a vote for getting this. Couldn't imagine they'd used such a small pagesize (without being aware of it) :-)

Comment: I assume the ps=2 example was an exaggeration :)

Comment: Yeah, with the Obs in sequence I took it too literally.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are trying to do. You have TITLE1 and TITLE2, so it looks like you are trying to suppress two title lines (which may not be there even).

If you want to suppress all column headings, you can't do it with PRINT. REPORT, on the other hand, has an option to suppress them.

If you can't use REPORT, you could use DEFINE to set the column titles to blanks, but you'd still have the lines.

I don't know SAS (about three minutes of internet searching) but there may be other ways to do what you want if you just want an output file.

There is lots of documentation available, easily located.